# How to display task name in CruiseControl.NET while processing

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, nant, tasklist

I have installed CruiseControl.NET and created project with 3 tasks on taskList in nAnt. But when I run project to process on CruiseControl.NET I see only that:

Executing Nant :BuildFile: ..\project.build Targets: compile, test, docu

And my project is processing and processing ages and does not stop. And I can not figure out if it is in compile, test or docu. Is there any way to see or set project so that I can see what is current processing?

I mean that I would like to see if currently it is doing compile, test or docu.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't display as it is building, once it has finished the 'NAnt Build Timing Report' will show exactly how long each target took.

Answer (score 1):

Use [NAnt CCNet Listener plugin](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNETCOMM/Viewing+build+progress+with+Nant+and+MSBuild) so that CruiseControl.Net will print project output while it is building.

Unfortunately, normal reports that CruiseControl.Net produces for NAnt may not show anything when the build times out - but using the plugin, the build output will be visible in the web dashboard and with CCTray.